# Why use bind instead of function call?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, bind

What is the advantage of using boost::bind in this case

```
std::for_each(participants_.begin(), participants_.end(),
    boost::bind(&chat_participant::deliver, _1, boost::ref(msg)));
```

instead of

```
for(iterator actual = participants_.begin(); actual != participants_.end(); ++actual)
    (*actual)->deliver(msg);
```

[Link to the whole code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp) (this is a simple server example provided by boost tutorials).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's simply that pre C++11, algorithms were generally recommended over plain for-loops for most things. In theory, it's easier to understand the purpose of the code, as you don't have to understand the whole loop implementation first. for_each is perhaps an extreme though, since its for-loop implementation would be the simplest.

Before lambda functions, 'boost::bind' was simply a requirement if you wanted to use the algorithm without defining a custom functor.

Nowadays, with range-based for loops, you'd just do this:

```
for (auto& participant : participants)
    participant->deliver(msg);
```

Algorithms are still better for more complicated loops though (especially now you don't have to use 'boost::bind').

Answer (score 2):

Both of them do the same job. `boost::bind` creates a function object, which works mostly like a function pointer in `C`. So the question maybe why they do that it the `C++` way.
`C++` is an Object-Oriented language, it comes with the standard library(STL), which provides several 
data structures(called class) such as container(list, set, map, iterator concept...etc) and others utilities. It also provides algorithms that work on that class(find, sort, filter..etc). So, for algorithms to work with these container in an uniform way, the container must follow some rules.
`std::for_each` is a part of STL algorithms, so that's the way it works.
But why the `C++` way looks good?

1. Just as @user673679 said, we don't lose focus on implement the loop anymore.
2. Traditionally loops create inner blocks, several inner blocks sometimes make it difficult to follow the logic.
3. You can reuse the functions' work on single element.